# Having trouble with basic linq to XML query

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get a very simple LINQ to XML query to work and just can't wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong.  I've done it similarly in C# just fine but for some reason I'm struggling with the same thing in VB.

I'm using the following page as my guide in addition to having searched around this forum:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387053.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

For my XML, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xmlroot>
    <customer>
        <name>test_customer</name>
        <data>data</data>
    </customer>
</xmlroot>
```

For my VB, I have:

```
Dim XMLFile As XDocument = XDocument.Load("file.xml")
Dim name_arg = "test_customer"

Dim customer As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From el In XMLFile.Root.<customer> Where el.<name>.Value = name_arg Select el

If (customer.Count <= 0) Then
    Throw New Exception("Customer name not found in file.xml")
End If
```

I get the exception thrown even though it looks pretty straightforward to me that it should work, i.e., the count of customers should be 1.  I've also tried:

```
Dim customer As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From el In XMLFile.Descendants("customer") Where el.Element("name").Value = name_arg Select el
```

No luck.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Edit:

I also tried:

```
Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load("file.xml")
```

...to load my XML document, more like the msdn page, and changed my query to:

```
Dim customer As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From el In root.<customer> Where el.<name>.Value = name_arg Select el
```

...still with no luck.

Comment: FYI - I copied and pasted your XML file and first code block into a test project and it works fine for me. `customer.Count` = 1, as expected.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  In my XML file I had white space I wasn't accounting for that I removed when I copied here and changed to remove the real customer information.  Argh, I feel dumb.